# Search cost on Tree with ordered nodes

Tags: algorithm, sorting

**Context:** I am building a FoundationDB, and I am thinking about which key use first

Let's say we have this set of elements :

```
{AP,AQ,AR,BP,BQ,BR}
```

and we want to build a tree from it. One way is to group by the first character first, and then by the second, obtaining

```
          root
     +-----+------+
     +            +
     A            B
+----+----+  +----+----+
|    |    |  |    |    |
+    +    +  +    +    +
P    Q    R  P    Q    R
```

One other possible way is to group first by the second character, and then by the first, obtaining:

```
           root
   +--------+--------+
   +        +        +
   P        Q        R
+--+-+   +--+--+   +-+--+
+    +   +     +   +    +
A    B   A     B   A    B
```

Assuming the probability distribution of the strings is uniform, which one leads to the fastest search time? In general, is best to having  an high number of branches on the top levels or the trees or on the bottom ones?

Answer (score 0):

First solution will lead to choosing one out of 2 options and then choosing one out of 3 options, while the second will first make a choice one out of three and then one out of two. Theoretically both should be approximately the same.

EDIT: as per your comment. In case you have two layers where the number of choices is significantly different like 30 and 1000000 I advice you to put the 30 options on the higher level and then have the 1000000 ones on the lower level. I believe caching will speed up the lower level more in similar cases.

Comment: I think that too, but since in my case the data space will be much wider, with 30 possibilities for the first key and about 1 million for the second, that approximately could make a difference :) that's why i'd like to have some sort of proof of their equal behavior

Comment: @kaharas in case the sizes of the two sets are so much different I would advice you to use first the smaller set(i.e. the one with 30 possibilities). The difference is that caching will be more efficient for the 1000000 possibilities on the second layer if they are continous.